# Как отследить заполнение input?

Tags: javascript

```js
let persons = document.querySelectorAll(".counter-block-input")[0],
  restDays = document.querySelectorAll(".counter-block-input")[1],
  place = document.getElementById("select"),
  totalValue = document.getElementById("total"),
  counter = document.querySelector(".counter"),
  personsSum = 0,
  daysSum = 0,
  total = 0;

totalValue.innerHTML = 0;


persons.addEventListener("change", function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[\D]/g, "");
  personsSum = +this.value;
  total = (daysSum + personsSum) * 4000;

  if (restDays.value == "" || persons.value == "") {
    totalValue.innerHTML = 0;
  } else {
    totalValue.innerHTML = total * place.options[place.selectedIndex].value;
  }
  if (this.value == 0) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/0/, "");
  }
});

restDays.addEventListener("change", function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[\D]/g, "");
  daysSum = this.value;
  total = (daysSum + personsSum) * 4000;

  if (persons.value == "" || restDays.value == "") {
    totalValue.innerHTML = 0;
  } else {
    totalValue.innerHTML = total * place.options[place.selectedIndex].value;
  }
  if (this.value == 0) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/0/, "");
  }
});

place.addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (restDays.value == "" || persons.value == "") {
    totalValue.innerHTML = 0;
  } else {
    let a = total;
    totalValue.innerHTML = a * this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="counter" id="price">
  <div class="counter-title">Рассчитайте стоимость вашего отдыха
  </div>
  <div class="counter-block">
    <div class="counter-block-option">Количество людей</div>
    <input type="number" min="1" step="1" class="counter-block-input">
  </div>
  <div class="counter-block">
    <div class="counter-block-option">На сколько дней</div>
    <input type="number" min="1" step="1" class="counter-block-input">
  </div>
  <div class="counter-block">
    <div class="counter-block-option">Выберете базу</div>
    <select name="place" id="select">
      <option id="mumbai" value="1">Индия, Мумбай</option>
      <option id="kerala" value="1.5">Индия, Керала</option>
      <option id="varanasi" value="1.8">Индия, Варанаси</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="counter-total">
    Общая сумма<br>
    <span id="total">20456</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Помогите пофиксить калькулятор.
Необходимо чтобы если пользователь заполнил оба поля, а потом очистил одно из них - общая сумма всё равно рассчиталась.

Comment: Зачем столько классов, почти на каждый элемент свой? Есть группирование, затем наследование и наконец каскадирование.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы установил минимально возможное значение для кол-ва людей и дней, т.к. сомневаюсь, что могут поехать 0 человек на какой-то период в Индию или 10 человек в ту же Индию на 0 дней. Но вам видней, поэтому такой вариант:

```js
const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.counter-block-input')];

const recalc = () => {
  inputs.forEach(el => el.value = el.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''));
  total.textContent = inputs.reduce((a, b) => (+a.value || 0) + (+b.value || 0)) * 4000 * select.value;
};

inputs.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('input', recalc));
select.addEventListener('change', recalc);
```

```html
<div class="counter" id="price">
  <div class="counter-title">Рассчитайте стоимость вашего отдыха
  </div>
  <div class="counter-block">
    <div class="counter-block-option">Количество людей</div>
    <input type="number" min="1" step="1" class="counter-block-input">
  </div>
  <div class="counter-block">
    <div class="counter-block-option">На сколько дней</div>
    <input type="number" min="1" step="1" class="counter-block-input">
  </div>
  <div class="counter-block">
    <div class="counter-block-option">Выберете базу</div>
    <select name="place" id="select">
      <option id="mumbai" value="1">Индия, Мумбай</option>
      <option id="kerala" value="1.5">Индия, Керала</option>
      <option id="varanasi" value="1.8">Индия, Варанаси</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="counter-total">
    Общая сумма<br>
    <span id="total">0</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: это Ваш юбилейный 1111 ответ =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ осмелюсь предположить, что юбилейный будет таки 1024 :-)